# 'str' object has no attribute 'save' | Django Views: Having a button that triggers a global setting variable to be saved to a Model field

Tags: python, django

I am working on a terms and conditions functionality for my app. Unfortunately I am pretty new to django and need some help.

I am getting the following error when I submit my form in the /terms template:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'save'
```

This is my terms.html template:

```
<p>Please accept the terms and coditions before proceeding</p>

<form  method='post' action='/terms/'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <p><input class='btn' type='submit' value='submit'/></p>
</form>
```

This is my related view in views.py

```
def terms(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, "terms.html")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Profile.filed_terms = TERMS
        Profile.filed_terms.save()
        return redirect(reverse(guest))
```

TERMS is a global variable I have set in my settings.py

Why am i getting this error. I am guessing I am not passing an object in my views during the POST request but I do not know why?

Comment: What is `Profile`? A model class?

Comment: yes profile is a model class

Answer (score 1):

If `TERMS` is a string (as it appears to be), then the error makes complete sense. You assign a string to `Profile.filed_terms`, then in the very next line attempt to call a `.save()` method on it. Strings do not have a `save()` method, hence the error.

Comment: hmm yes it is a string, how would I save the new Profile with the updated filed_terms field?

Comment: @Javier does your `Profile` class have a `save()` method? You should probably call that instead.

Comment: no it does not, should it? Is there no easier way to save updated column on a database? With rails you can just save a change like this in the console or controller super easily.

Comment: @Javier without knowing what your code looks like, there is absolutely no way I can answer your question. I suggest reading through the docs on Django models and modifying your code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You make the comparison to Rails, but you haven't done *anything* like you would do in Rails here.

Firstly, Profile is a class, not an instance. In Rails you don't set database values on the class, you set them on an instance, which you would need to create first. You do that in Django too.

Also in Rails you don't call `save` on string attributes, you call it on the instance as well.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    profile = Profile()
    profile.filed_terms = TERMS
    profile.save()
```

However, this still makes absolutely no sense, because all you're doing is filling your database table with rows that contain exactly the same text and nothing else. Are you trying to create a profile associated with the current user? If so, you should say so.